# How to use Activity code into Fragment class in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a "Activity" class code which I want to copy into "Fragment" class but unaware of Fragment structure, can someone help me to do that? Below are my two classes :

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] application = { "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "HIJ" };                     
    private String[] device = { "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "HIJ" }; 
    private RadioGroup radioGroup1;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup2;
    private RadioButton btn;
    private RadioButton btn2;
    private String text1;
    private String text2;
    RadioButton button1;
    RadioButton button2;
    Button selectall;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        checkButtonClick();
        drawRadiobuttons();

    }

    private void checkButtonClick() {

        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
                responseText.append("");

                // Get selected radiobuttons
                if (radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                    text1 = btn.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("Button", "Text 1 : " + text1);
                }

                if (radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                    text2 = btn2.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("Button", "Text 2 : " + text2);
                }


                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Data Posting : APPLICATION : "
                                + text1 + " \nDEVICE : " + text2,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });

    }

    private void drawRadiobuttons(){

        radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio2);

        ViewGroup hourButtonLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        for (int i = 0; i < application.length; i++) {
            button1 = new RadioButton(this);
            button1.setId(i);
            button1.setText(application[i]);
            hourButtonLayout.addView(button1);

            radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup mRadioGroup2,
                                int checkedId2) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < mRadioGroup2.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                btn = (RadioButton) mRadioGroup2.getChildAt(i);
                                int t = mRadioGroup2.getId();
                                System.out.println(t);

                                if (btn.getId() == checkedId2) {
                                    text1 = btn.getText().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "You selected : " + text1,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

        ViewGroup hourButtonLayout2 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio2); 
        for (int i = 0; i < device.length; i++) {
            button2 = new RadioButton(this);
            button2.setId(i);
            button2.setText(device[i]);
            hourButtonLayout2.addView(button2);

            radioGroup2
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup mRadioGroup,
                                int checkedId) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < mRadioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                btn2 = (RadioButton) mRadioGroup.getChildAt(i);
                                int t = mRadioGroup.getId();
                                System.out.println(t);

                                if (btn2.getId() == checkedId) {
                                    text2 = btn2.getText().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "You selected : " + text2,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

    }

}
```

The same running "Activity" code i want to add into "ImageFragment" code

ImageFragment.java

```
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {
    int fragVal;
    private String[] application = { "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "HIJ" };                     
    private String[] device = { "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "HIJ" }; 
    private RadioGroup radioGroup1;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup2;
    private RadioButton btn;
    private RadioButton btn2;
    private String text1;
    private String text2;
    RadioButton button1;
    RadioButton button2;
    Button selectall;
    Context thiscontext;

    static ImageFragment init(int val) {
        ImageFragment truitonFrag = new ImageFragment();
        // Supply val input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("val", val);
        truitonFrag.setArguments(args);
        return truitonFrag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fragVal = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("val") : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        thiscontext = container.getContext();
        View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        Button myButton = (Button) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
                responseText.append("");

                // Get selected radiobuttons
                if (radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                    text1 = btn.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("Button", "Text 1 : " + text1);
                }

                if (radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                    text2 = btn2.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("Button", "Text 2 : " + text2);
                }


                Toast.makeText(
                        thiscontext,
                        "Data Posting : APPLICATION : "
                                + text1 + " \nDEVICE : " + text2,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });


        //Draw Radiobuttons

        radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio2);

        ViewGroup hourButtonLayout = (ViewGroup) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        for (int i = 0; i < application.length; i++) {
            button1 = new RadioButton(this);
            button1.setId(i);
            button1.setText(application[i]);
            hourButtonLayout.addView(button1);

            radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup mRadioGroup2,
                                int checkedId2) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < mRadioGroup2.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                btn = (RadioButton) mRadioGroup2.getChildAt(i);
                                int t = mRadioGroup2.getId();
                                System.out.println(t);

                                if (btn.getId() == checkedId2) {
                                    text1 = btn.getText().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(thiscontext,
                                            "You selected : " + text1,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

        ViewGroup hourButtonLayout2 = (ViewGroup) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio2); 
        for (int i = 0; i < device.length; i++) {
            button2 = new RadioButton(this);
            button2.setId(i);
            button2.setText(device[i]);
            hourButtonLayout2.addView(button2);

            radioGroup2
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup mRadioGroup,
                                int checkedId) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < mRadioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                btn2 = (RadioButton) mRadioGroup.getChildAt(i);
                                int t = mRadioGroup.getId();
                                System.out.println(t);

                                if (btn2.getId() == checkedId) {
                                    text2 = btn2.getText().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(thiscontext,
                                            "You selected : " + text2,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }



        return layoutView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

copy your activity's `onCreate` code into `onCreateView` of `Fragment`.

in fragment you have to use `layoutView` to get views instances.

like your below code to get button.

```
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
```

would be converted into

```
    Button myButton = (Button)layoutView.findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
```

you can declare layoutView as a class variable instead of local variable in onCreateView to make it accessible in whole fragment.

```
View layoutView; // making it accessible
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
```

and do not forget to return `layoutView` instance from `onCreateView`.

above suggestion are basics, now post question for specific requirement/issue, to get more helpful answer.

**Edit** instead of **this** use **getActivity()** to get context instance.

like in `button1 = new RadioButton(this)` you should use

`button1 = new RadioButton(**getActivity()**);`

reason for above is, in activity **this** gives you instance of context as Activity is sub class of Context, but in fragment **this** can not give you access of the same,hence you would need to use getActivity() or getActivity().getBaseContext() to get context instance where required.

Comment: Hey Thanks @AAnkit - I did as you suggested, getting one error in line "button1 = new RadioButton(this)". Error is "The constructor RadioButton(ImageFragment) is undefined". How to overcome this ?

Comment: sure @AAnkit will change that but what do i do of button error? I hope you got that?

Comment: see my updated answer. I said use getActivity() instead of ''this'' to get activity isnstance.

Comment: Cool, see updated answer, I have added basic understanding for using getActivity instead of ''this''.