# How to retrieve values from FireBase to JSONArray?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got a source code of a food delivery app from [git](https://github.com/liguanzhu92/Foody). he is parsing a website and displaying the menu items, I guess to see the

[image: screenshot of website]

instead of this I have created a fire-base database and stored one food item for testing

[image: screenshot of fire-base]

I want to display my item from the fire-base to the app menu I will show the code of all food item fragment,

```
package com.example.guanzhuli.foody.HomePage.fragment;

public class AllTabFragment extends Fragment {

    private String baseUrl = "http://rjtmobile.com/ansari/fos/fosapp/fos_food_loc.php?city=";
    private String TAG = "ALLFOOD";
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("menu");

    ArrayList<Food> foods = new ArrayList<>();

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private AllFoodAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    String foodName;

    public AllTabFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_tab, container, false);

        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    foodName = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();

                    String foodPrice = snapshot.child("prize").getValue().toString();

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), foodName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        // Request Data From Web Service
        if (foods.size() == 0) {
            objRequestMethod();
        }

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_all);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        adapter = new AllFoodAdapter(getActivity(), foods);

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new AllFoodAdapter.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, String data) {
                Bundle itemInfo = new Bundle();
                for (int i = 0; i < foods.size(); i++) {
                    if (foods.get(i).getId() == Integer.valueOf(data)) {
                        itemInfo.putInt("foodId", foods.get(i).getId());
                        itemInfo.putString("foodName", foods.get(i).getName());

                        // itemInfo.putString("foodName", foodName);
                        itemInfo.putString("foodCat", foods.get(i).getCategory());
                        itemInfo.putString("foodRec", foods.get(i).getRecepiee());
                        itemInfo.putDouble("foodPrice", foods.get(i).getPrice());
                        itemInfo.putString("foodImage", foods.get(i).getImageUrl());
                        break;
                    }

                }
                FoodDetailFragment foodDetailFragment = new FoodDetailFragment();
                foodDetailFragment.setArguments(itemInfo);
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)
                        .replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, foodDetailFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(AllTabFragment.class.getName())
                        .commit();
            }
        });
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

    private void objRequestMethod() {
        HomePageActivity.showPDialog();

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, buildUrl(), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                Log.d(TAG, jsonObject.toString());

                try {
                    JSONArray foodsJsonArr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Food");
                    for (int i = 0; i < foodsJsonArr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = foodsJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = c.getString("FoodId");
                        String name = c.getString("FoodName");
                        String recepiee = c.getString("FoodRecepiee");
                        String price = c.getString("FoodPrice");
                        String category = c.getString("FoodCategory");
                        String thumb = c.getString("FoodThumb");
                        final Food curFood = new Food();
                        curFood.setCategory(category);
                        curFood.setName(name);
                        curFood.setRecepiee(recepiee);
                        curFood.setPrice(Double.valueOf(price));
                        curFood.setId(Integer.valueOf(id));
                        curFood.setImageUrl(thumb);

                        foods.add(curFood);
                        //                        Log.e("Current Food", curFood.getName());

                        ImageLoader imageLoader = VolleyController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
                        imageLoader.get(thumb, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Image Load Error: " + error.getMessage());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
                                if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                                    curFood.setImage(response.getBitmap());
                                    //                                    Log.e("SET IMAGE", curFood.getName());
                                    adapter.notifyData(foods);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        foods.get(i).setImage(curFood.getImage());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }

                HomePageActivity.disPDialog();
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "ERROR" + volleyError.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), volleyError.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                HomePageActivity.disPDialog();
            }
        });
        VolleyController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }

    private String buildUrl() {
        return baseUrl + HomePageActivity.City;
    }

}
```

I got food name from fire-base and stored in the string called "foodname" Now I want to display it in the menu, how can I do it?
if my question is wrong please forgive me, please help me

```
package com.example.guanzhuli.foody.HomePage.adapter;

public class AllFoodAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllHolder> implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<Food> foods;
    public String TAG = "ALLFOOD";

    //
    //    public AllFoodAdapter(Context context) {
    //        mContext = context;
    //    }
    public AllFoodAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Food> foods) {
        mContext = context;
        this.foods = foods;
    }

    @Override
    public AllHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.cardview_food, parent, false);
        AllHolder allHolder = new AllHolder(v);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        return allHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AllHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextId.setText(String.valueOf(foods.get(position).getId()));
        holder.mTextName.setText(foods.get(position).getName());
        holder.mTextPrice.setText(String.valueOf(foods.get(position).getPrice()));
        holder.mTextCategory.setText(foods.get(position).getCategory());
        holder.mImageView.setImageBitmap(foods.get(position).getImage());

        holder.itemView.setTag(foods.get(position).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return foods.size();
    }

    public void notifyData(ArrayList<Food> foods) {
        //        Log.d("notifyData ", foods.size() + "");
        this.foods = foods;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static interface OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {

        void onItemClick(View view, String data);
    }

    private OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener = null;

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener listener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
            mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, String.valueOf(view.getTag()));
        } else {
            Log.e("CLICK", "ERROR");
        }
    }
}

class AllHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    NetworkImageView mImage;
    ImageView mImageView;
    TextView mTextId, mTextName, mTextCategory, mTextPrice;

    public AllHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        // mImage = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_img);
        mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_img);
        mTextId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_id);
        mTextName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_name);
        mTextPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_price);
        mTextId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_id);
        mTextCategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_category);
    }
}
```

Please help me, because it is an important project for me

Comment: Did you want to show it in List

Comment: yeah , like a list of menu items @Sniffer

Comment: Hey @JaisonJoseph do mark the answer as correct, by clicking the V looking button next to the answer, it helps the future readers and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the strings you have received from firebase in a new activity as a list, you can declare an `ArrayList` and then add those strings to it and then with an adapter set it to display.

In code it looks something like this:

```java
private ArrayList array;
    private ListView listView;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private String curName;

    //set them 

    listView = findViewById(R.id.list1);
    array = new ArrayList<String>();

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("menu");    

    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    array.add(ds.child("name").getValue(String.class));

                }


                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Main6Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: is this a new class

Comment: or where i should add this ?

Comment: This can be placed in your new activity where you want to put the list of the food items

Comment: i have a fragment can i add in the same fragment ?

Comment: Yes, with some care though, read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421381/how-to-use-activity-code-into-fragment-class-in-android

Comment: bro i tot of editing the same code instaed of creating new one , like changing the values of adapter

Comment: You can just understand the idea of the code and implement it yourself. This is based on storing the strings and displaying them with adapter. That's it. You may try the code and see if it works.

Comment: its a recycle view

Comment: curFood.setName(name); when i change name to foodname as string from firebase its not displaying why ? when i toast 'foodname' its retrieving from firebase but in food name its not displaying

Comment: I didn't get you, can you tell which line in your code are you referring to?

Comment: there is a line like curFood.setName(name);

Comment: if i change to curFood.setName(foodName);  it is not geting anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182263/discussion-between-pradyuman-dixit-and-jaison-joseph).

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflow was not conceived to get complete code solutions. We can only help you on some point. Other than that, you need to think to use the Food class for read and write values on your db. When you retrive the values, get it as a Food object casting it by method **dataSnapshot.getValue("object class");**...

In your case you need a code like this:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Food food = snapshot.getValue(Food.class);
        //here you need to add the food object to a list and after the for diplay it with adapter.
       //for example foodsList.add(food);
    }
    foodsList.setAdapter(myAdepter); //ecc
}
```

If you need help, please tell us more

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be loading the food items from the database, and reading the values from them. All that's left to do, is add each item to the `foods` array, and tell the adapter that its data has changed:

```
mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String foodName = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            String foodPrice = snapshot.child("prize").getValue(String.class);

            Food food = new Food();
            food.setName(name);
            food.setPrice(Double.valueOf(price));
            foods.add(food);
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

Comment: i want to store this as array